# Trying to embed a YouTube video using react-native-youtube module

Tags: react-native

I am trying to embed a youtube video using the react-native-youtube module with no success.  I can build my react-native project fine and the app comes up but all I see is a black screen where the video player should be located.

[image]

```
<View>
   <YouTube
       apiKey={API_KEY}
       videoId={VIDEO_ID}   
       play         
       fullscreen   
       loop={false}            
       onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
       onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
       onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
       onError={e => this.setState({ error: e.error })}
       style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300 }}
     />
   </View>
```

Comment: Did you mean this module https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube?

Comment: Yes.  Looking at the docs this could be an issue with the version of react-native.  I will try the version that they have this working on.

Comment: Tried the older version and still having the same issue.

Comment: ok, I also installed the youtube apk for the emulator and no luck with that as well.  I also downloaded the android example from  github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube and got the same issue with that code.

Comment: I gave up on this module and just used this instead.
<WebView
    style={videoStyle}
    source={{ uri: `url${video.id.videoId}?
 version=3&
 autoplay=0&
 showinfo=0&
 controls=0&
 modestbranding=1&
 fs=1&
 rel=0` 
     }}
 />

Comment: Cool. Finally you found the solution.